# Django Admin error out that a field that is missing from the form

Tags: django-models, django-admin

Getting an error with my admin.py file:
'BaseAdmin.fieldsets[1][1]['fields']' refers to field 'publish_on' that is missing from the form.

my class looks like:

```
class Base(models.Model):
    ...
    publish_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, db_index=True)
    ...
```

My admin.py looks like:

```
class BaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    fieldsets = [
        ('Dates', {
            'fields': ('publish_on',)
        }),
    ]
```

if I change out my admin class with 'pass' or just register with the model class then the date time field shows up.

Comment: Are you using any custom form?

Comment: No custom forms.  If I use my custom admin class and do not define any fieldsets then not all of my model fields show up...again missing some datetime fields.

Comment: In my models for my datetimefields I had auto_now=True - if I remove those, then the fields will display.  Anyone else see this kind of behavior?

Comment: I'm using django 1.2.1 btw - I'll upgrade to the latest and see if the auto_now issue is there still.

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516799/django-modeladmin-fieldsets-field-date-missing-from-the-form

Answer (score 6):

This error is caused by auto_now and also by auto_now_add. To remedy that add

```
readonly_fields = ("publish_on",)
```

in your BaseAdmin (only in django 1.2 and newer).

Answer (score 4):

If you do want to use auto_now_add, but then leave open the possibility of changing the date, you could use `default=datetime.now` in the model field. This sets a default in the admin, but lets the user change it, and it works in inlines.