# A better way of setting values in CreateView?

Tags: python, django

`models.py`:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    post_body = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('published')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return u'/entries/%d' % self.id
```

`forms.py`:

```
class NewPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ('title', 'post_body')
```

So, I was trying to make a view for users to post a new post into blog. BlogPost model has 4 fields - `title`, `post_body`, `user`, and `pub_date`. User should be able to fill the `title` and `post_body`, while the other two should be filled automatically. First thing I tried was this:

```
class NewPostView(generic.edit.CreateView):
    model = BlogPost
    form_class = NewPostForm

    def get_initial(self):
        return {'pub_date': timezone.now(),
                'user': self.request.user}
```

But the only thing it does is providing the default values for html form. After additional research this is the code that ended up working:

```
class NewPostView(generic.edit.CreateView):
    model = BlogPost
    form_class = NewPostForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = self.request.user
        obj.pub_date = timezone.now()
        obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(obj.get_absolute_url())
```

So, while overriding form_valid method worked, I don't feel like it's how it should be done maybe? Is there a better place to put this actions into? What is the conventional way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's exactly how its done, except for your `form_save` method (which should not return a response):

1. You can use [`auto_now_add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) to your `pub_date` field, it will add the current timestamp when the model is first created (saving you the trouble).
2. You can also use a field from the model in the `success_url` parameter, like this:

   ```
   class CreateNewPost(generic.edit.CreateView):
       model = BlogPost
       form_class = NewPostForm
       success_url = '/entries/%(id)s'

       def form_valid(self, form):
           obj = form.save(commit=False)
           obj.user = self.request.user
           obj.pub_date = timezone.now()
           obj.save()
   ```
3. If you need a custom return URL, you should override [`get_success_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.get_success_url), instead of returning a response from `form_valid`.

Comment: After adding `auto_add_now=True` I started getting this error: `'BlogAdmin.fieldsets[1][1]['fields']' refers to field 'pub_date' that is missing from the form.`

Found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516799/django-modeladmin-fieldsets-field-date-missing-from-the-form

Comment: Another thing - after setting `success_url` and removing `ResponseRedirect` from `form_valid` I'm getting this error: `The view blog.views.NewPostView didn't return an HttpResponse object.`

Answer (score 13):

You can override `form_valid` but then call out to `super().form_valid(form)` in the return statement. You won't have to worry about saving the form, saving the object, or returning the HttpResponseRedirtect. All of that will be handled by the super. All you need to do is set the values of the `form.instance` that you want to control behind the scenes.

**views.py**

```
class NewPostView(generic.edit.CreateView):
    model = BlogPost
    form_class = NewPostForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.pub_date = timezone.now()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

That would be a clean approach to adding the values behind the scenes that doesn't require you to do any more logic than adding the values. You can find a reference to that logic in the django documentation at:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user

---

Ideally, for the `pub_date` you would want to set the field to record the creation time automatically with `auto_now_add`.

**models.py**

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    post_body = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('published', auto_add_now=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return u'/entries/%d' % self.id
```

You can find the documentation on the DateTimeField and its reference to the `auto_add_now` parameter at link that follows. It also has a `auto_add` that will update every time the entry is modified, in case you wanted a `last_edited_date` field.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField

---

Also, there is a possibility that your user could access the form without being logged in. You would either need to handle the case for `self.request.user` not being set, or you can user the `LoginRequiredMixin` to only allow logged in users to access this form. I have had an easier time using the mixin.

The resulting `view.py` with all the above mentioned changes would look like the following.

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import CreateView

from .forms import NewPostForm
from .models import BlogPost

class NewPostView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = BlogPost
    form_class = NewPostForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 3):

The other route to doing this is to put the save behaviour on the form itself.

```
class NewPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ('title', 'post_body')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(NewPostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self):
        obj = super(NewPostForm, self).save(commit=False)
        obj.user = self.user
        obj.pub_date = timezone.now()
        obj.save()
        return obj
```

This nicely encapsulates the logic in a more reusable way outside of the view.

You'd need to override `get_form_kwargs` on the view to pass the user in, or use the `UserFormKwargsMixin` class from [`django-braces`](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces) in order to ensure `user` gets passed by the view when initializing the form.

Note that [`django-braces`](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces) also provides a `UserKwargModelFormMixin` that you can use on the form instead of overriding `__init__()`.  If you take the braces approach, you'd end up with something like this:

**forms.py**:

```
class NewPostForm(UserKwargModelFormMixin, forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ('title', 'post_body')

    def save(self):
        obj = super(NewPostForm, self).save(commit=False)
        obj.user = self.user
        obj.pub_date = timezone.now()
        obj.save()
        return obj
```

**views.py**:

```
class NewPostView(UserFormKwargsMixin, generic.edit.CreateView):
    model = BlogPost
    form_class = NewPostForm
```

Comment: I'm getting `KeyError` when trying to `pop` `'user'` from `kwargs`. I guess it's not passed to `__init__` of NewPostForm?

Comment: That's right yeah, make sure you're either overriding `get_form_kwargs` on the view, or including `UserFormKwargsMixin` on the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can also give the default value as `default = timezone.now()` in your model so whenever the object is created it will automatically take current time.